# get element by class name in javascript is driving me crazy

Tags: javascript, html

hello can someone help me with this code am trying to create multiple posts that contains a paragraph and like and heart and an image but when i create the like and the heart i get confused i want when someone clicks the like icon it says 1 like but it only works with one post i tried doing that with html and javascript

```js
var like = document.getElementsByClassName("likes");
var heart = document.getElementsByClassName("heart");

function iconlike(x) {
  x.style.color = 'red';
  if (x.style.color == 'red') {
    like[0].innerHTML = 1;
  }
}

function iconheart(x) {
  x.style.color = 'red';
  if (x.style.color == 'red') {
    heart[0].innerHTML = 1;
  }
}
```

```html
<!-- the first div -->
<div class="container">
  <section class="content">
    <figure class="parent">
      <!-- the image for the post -->
      <img src="./assests/avatar.png" style="width: 60px;" class="avatar" name="avatar">
      <label for="avatar"><h2>saif alhaider</h2></label>
      <img src="./assests/1.jpg" style="width: 100%;">
      <figure>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#" onclick="iconlike(this); return false"><i class="fas fa-thumbs-up"></i></a></li>
          <span class="likes">0 likes</span>
          <li><a href="#" onclick="iconheart(this); return false"><i class="fas fa-heart"></i></a></li>
          <span class="heart">0 heart</span>
        </ul>
      </figure>
      <!-- the discription -->
      <figcaption>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure
          dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
      </figcaption>
    </figure>
  </section>
</div>
<!-- the second div -->
<div class="container">
  <section class="content">
    <figure class="parent">
      <!-- the image for the post -->
      <img src="./assests/avatar.png" style="width: 60px;" class="avatar" name="avatar">
      <label for="avatar"><h2>saif alhaider</h2></label>
      <img src="./assests/2.jpg" style="width: 100%;">
      <figure>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#" onclick="iconlike(this); return false"><i class="fas fa-thumbs-up"></i></a></li>
          <span class="likes">0 likes</span>
          <li><a href="#" onclick="iconheart(this); return false"><i class="fas fa-heart"></i></a></li>
          <span class="heart">0 heart</span>
        </ul>
      </figure>
      <!-- the discription -->
      <figcaption>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure
          dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
      </figcaption>
    </figure>
  </section>
</div>
```

Comment: Could you please make a little effort and write your question correctly, with punctuation and capital letters? Explain your problem, what's the current behaviour, what's the expected one? Thanks. Nobody will help you if you just throw code and a bunch of unformatted words at them.

Comment: Please read: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: `like[0]` will always update the first item in the collection. You need to find the sibling `likes` item

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not clear for me, Hope this is what you are looking for

```
var like = document.getElementsByClassName("likes");
var heart = document.getElementsByClassName("heart");

function iconlike(x) {
  x.style.color = 'red';
  if (x.style.color == 'red') 
  {
  for (var i = 0; i < like.length; i++) {
    {
      like[i].innerHTML = 1;
    }

  }
}

function iconheart(x) {
  x.style.color = 'red';
  if (x.style.color == 'red')
  {
    for (var i = 0; i < heart.length; i++) {
    {
      heart[i].innerHTML = 1;
    }

  }
}
```